# Can you change the IAM Identity Center Access Portal URL subdomain after it's been customized?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iam-identity-center

I know that [the documentation for this says that it cannot be edited](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/howtochangeURL.html) but surely there are plenty of use cases for this. For instance, if an employee mistakenly inputted the subdomain in IAM Identity Center or if a company was rebranding, there would need to be some way to change the login address.

One workaround that I'm considering is to [delete our entire IAM IC configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/regions.html) and rebuild it from scratch. Would this work? Obviously I would rather not do this but from what I'm seeing it's our only option.